# Stuck on maintenance mode

Tags: functions, maintenance

I put my site in maintenance mode using this hook in `functions.php`,

```
function activate_maintenance_mode() {
    //If the current user is NOT an 'Administrator' or NOT 'Super Admin' then display Maintenance Page.
    if ( !(current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ||  current_user_can( 'super admin' ))) {
        //Kill WordPress execution and display HTML maintenance message. 
        wp_die('<h1>Sitio en mantenimiento</h1><p>Nuestro sitio esta actualemente en mantenimiento. 
            <br /><strong>Ya volvemos!</strong></p>', 'mantenimiento');
    }
}
//Hooks the 'activate_maintenance_mode' function on to the 'get_header' action.
add_action('get_header', 'activate_maintenance_mode');
```

and now I can't return back to normal mode.

**EDIT:** The problem had to be with W3 Total Cache plugin.

Comment: Did you add it to your functions.php file via your Dahsboard > Appearance > Editor or did you do this via an external text editor and FTP?

Comment: External editor + FTP

Comment: Just remove that code and you should be fine. BTW: not sure if `current_user_can( 'super admin' )` part with the space will work. You can try with any super admin caps like `current_user_can( 'manage_network' )`

Comment: I've commented it out I forgot to say!

Comment: If you had added this code via the Dashboard it would mean you would have to access it via FTP to remove it but as @Sisir said, as you already doing so via FTP, you can just remove it to get things working again.

Comment: Clear you browser cache.

Comment: I've just cleared my cache and keeps stucked. I was trying in Incognito mode before clearing the cache.

Comment: Does it has to be with W3C Total Cache plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the W3 total cache plugin, So The HTML code will be cached in the wp-content/cache folder. So Delete Cache folder from wp-content directory.

Now remove the function activate_maintenance_mode() and check the site now...

If the problem exists , Delete the W3 total Cache Constant from wp-config.php and clear your browser data and check the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is wrong, you are basically using WP_die for super admins when you say :

```
if ( !(current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ||  current_user_can( 'super admin' )))
```

I think the correct code should be

```
if ( !(current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&  !(current_user_can( 'super admin' ))))
```

Can you try this and let me know.
Praveen

Comment: ok, i've changed it. However I keep stucked, so I cannot see if it works.

Comment: Can you then alter it so that it is only  if ( !(current_user_can( 'administrator' ))  { wp_die();}